# How to give rights for one user(profile) to delete only one other user(profile) in jhipster

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster

I need to view the administration drop down to other authorities as well in jhipster. For that which file how should I change? I guess it should be navbar.html and the following line.

```
<li ng-class="{active: `vm.$state.includes('admin')`}"  ng-switch-when="true" has-authority="ROLE_ADMIN" uib-dropdown class="dropdown pointer">
```

How to pass multiple authorities there. Other authority should be ROLE_MEMBER. In the JHI_AUTHORITY table it was added. I tried the above code as follows. But didn't make the change which I need.

```
vm.$state.includes('admin','member')
```

has-any-authority works as in the following answer. Then I need to give privileges for members to delete users which has the profile of ROLE_STUDENT. How should I do that?

```
.state('user-management.delete', {
        url: '/{login}/delete',
        data: {
            authorities: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_MEMBER']
        },
```

There members and admin both can delete all the users. But I need to give rights for members to delete only students(ROLE_STUDENT). How should I implement that logic? May be it should be implemented inside UserResource.java following method.

```
@DeleteMapping("/users/{login:" + Constants.LOGIN_REGEX + "}")
@Timed
@Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.MEMBER})
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable String login) {
    log.debug("REST request to delete User: {}", login);
    boolean hasAuthorityAdmin = false;
    boolean hasAuthorityMember = false;
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
    hasAuthorityAdmin = authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN));
    hasAuthorityMember = authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.MEMBER));
    if (hasAuthorityAdmin) {
        // delete user
        userService.deleteUser(login);
    } else {
        if (hasAuthorityMember) {
            // delete user if it is a student
            if (userService.getAuthorities().size() == 4 && userService.getAuthorities().contains(AuthoritiesConstants.STUDENT)) {
                userService.deleteUser(login);
            }
        }
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createAlert("userManagement.deleted", login)).build();
}
```

There I guess mistake with this `if (userService.getAuthorities().size() == 4 && userService.getAuthorities().contains(AuthoritiesConstants.STUDENT))` condition. There if I can get the user role of which is going to delete, then we can check whether it is a ROLE_STUDENT. I think `deleteUser(@PathVariable String login)` if we can pass another parameter to get the user profile where going to delete we can resolve the problem. Or if we can find another method in userService to get the authorities which is going to delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it using **has-any-authority** :

```
<li ng-class="{active: `vm.$state.includes('admin')`}"  ng-switch-when="true" has-any-authority="ROLE_MEMBER, ROLE_ADMIN" uib-dropdown class="dropdown pointer">
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Then I need give privileges to delete only one kind of(profile) users. How should I change user-management.state.js for only that purpose?

Comment: Great. Following the update, I am not sure what you want to achieve. The users with roles ADMIN or MEMBER should be able to delete users with role STUDENT only ? Or the users with roles ADMIN can also delete users with any other role than STUDENT ?

Comment: Actually users with roles MEMBER can delete only users with role STUDENT. And ADMIN can delete anything

Answer (score 2):

Following the question update, here is what you could do to be able to delete a user with ROLE STUDENT if the current user has the role MEMBER :

```
    @DeleteMapping("/users/{login:" + Constants.LOGIN_REGEX + "}")
    @Timed
    @Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.MEMBER})
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable String login) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete User: {}", login);
        boolean hasAuthorityMember = false;
        boolean hasAuthorityAdmin = false;
        hasAuthorityMember = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().contains(AuthoritiesConstants.MEMBER);
        hasAuthorityAdmin = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().contains(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);
        if(hasAuthorityAdmin) {
            // delete user
            userService.deleteUser(login);
        } else {
            if(hasAuthorityMember) {
                // delete user if it is a student
                if(userService.getAuthorities().size()==1 && userService.getAuthorities().contains(AuthoritiesConstants.STUDENT)) {
                    userService.deleteUser(login);
                }
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createAlert( "userManagement.deleted", login)).build();
    }
```

Comment: There for  both hasAuthorityMember and hasAuthorityAdmin return value is false always. So couldn't delete it.

Comment: When you're on debug mode, what do you have for **SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()** and for **SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()** ?

Comment: when I logged in as system admin it is [ROLE_ADM
IN, ROLE_USER] for SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAu‌​thorities()

Comment: When I logged in as normal admin it is  [ROLE_ADMIN]. So I think contains should be changed as [ROLE_ADMIN]. Because AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN value is just ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: Sorry to tell that member can delete any user. I need to restrict it only to student. userService.getAuthorities() method will return all the roles. So that may be the reason. We have to find another method to get the user where I need to delete. So do u have any idea?

Comment: Sorry I got that a member can delete any user, but I don't understand what you want to be able to do now ? Which type of user can delete ONLY students ? Who students are able to delete ?

Comment: Actually member can't delete any user. Member can delete only students. But Admin can delete any user. That implementation was ok. Just that issue has to resolve

Comment: That means in the current implementation member can delete any user. I need to restrict it only to student deletion. if(userService.getAuthorities().size()==4 && userService.getAuthorities().contains(AuthoritiesConstants.STUDENT)) {        There we may need to get the row of  which we are going to delete and should check whether it is a student type role